# Trouble deleting .svn folders in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, tortoisesvn

I do a search on .svn using Explorer in my project directory and they come up fine.  But when I try to highlight all the .svn folders in my search results it appears that they are deleted by the dialog but they're stil there. I can't get rid of them!

Comment: it's so weird I keep getting a message saying the .svn folders no longer exist when trying to delete them.  And it's not that explorer is cached or anything, I even rebooted and each time I try to delete them through the search tool in Vista, I get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to delete the `.svn` folders in a working copy?

If you want a "clean" copy of any given tree version, you can easily use `SVN Export` (available from the Tortoise SVN menu).

Comment: obviously, the better solution :)

Comment: but I heard export doesn't export non-versioned files

Comment: I don't understand your workflow, or the way you are attempting to use Subversion. Why do you have important but non-versioned files in a Subversion working copy? At any rate, you can export and then copy the non-versioned files that did not get exported. Or, if you're feeling cool, you can: add all the important non-versioned files, create a branch with the working copy as the source so that the commit *to a new branch* picks up the added files, switch the working directory to point to the branch, and export. You can even switch back and delete the branch when you're done.

Comment: NO, I just wanted to disassociate my local folder with svn altogether...all the code as if I were to start from scratch because I wanted to re-add it fresh to a new repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it from the cmd line

I think...

> del /F /S *.svn.

Comment: nice, that deletes most but I still have some .svn folders lingering around

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the versioned folder to the destination folder using the right mouse button and when your mouse pointer is over the desired drop location let the button go and select the "SVN export all items here" option from the context menu that pops up. This should copy over both the versioned and unversioned files without the .svn directory. I hope its not some additional application that I installed that gives me this option but maybe you should try it.